# Boost Unit Test Entry Point Issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, boost

Here's the code I'm working with in Eclipse CDT (from the official boost doc http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int add(int i, int j) {
   return i + j;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test ) {
   // seven ways to detect and report the same error:
   BOOST_CHECK(add(2, 2) == 4);        // #1 continues on error

   BOOST_REQUIRE(add(2, 2) == 4);      // #2 throws on error

   if (add(2, 2) != 4)
      BOOST_ERROR("Ouch...");            // #3 continues on error

   if (add(2, 2) != 4)
      BOOST_FAIL("Ouch...");             // #4 throws on error

   if (add(2, 2) != 4)
      throw "Ouch..."; // #5 throws on error

   BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(add(2, 2) == 4,  // #6 continues on error
   "add(..) result: " << add( 2,2 ));

   BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(add(2, 2), 4);      // #7 continues on error
}
```

When I try to build it in Eclipse or the terminal, I get an error message regarding the lack of an entry point or main function:

```
08:33:51 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test_C++ ****
make all 
Building target: Test_C++
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "Test_C++"  ./src/test.o   -lboost_unit_test_framework
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test_C++] Error 1

08:33:52 Build Finished (took 742ms)
```

Putting a main function in the code causes the program to build fine, but then the tests are skipped entirely. I installed boost test using synaptic package manager so it should be almost plug and play minus the part where I specify the library(-l) as boost_unit_test_framework.

I've been able to get boost/test/minimal.hpp linking and working just fine, but unfortunately I haven't got boost/test/unit_test.hpp working nicely in Eclipse in which the unit test output is shown within the C/C++ Unit view. I've tried going through several official and unofficial boost documentation/tutorials and haven't been too successful. I'm trying to get to a point where I can start unit testing within Eclipse where it's somewhat similar to the comfortability of using JUnit inside Eclipse. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out I should have avoided installing framework libraries through the package manager. It's best to install from source so you know where everything is. These two docs helped:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792

and for generic situations dealing with shared libraries (i.e. right after the bjam installation phase):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

I'm not exactly sure where the package manager put the libraries, but I needed to verify the integrity of linking at link-time and at run-time by making sure I put the library files in /usr/local/lib and then following up with ldconfig.